# mysql wont start - innoDB: Database was not shut down normally

Tags: mysql

My office's mysql server is suddenly down and won't start. I used XAMPP.
when look into the log it shown like this:

```
130211  9:45:04 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130211  9:45:04 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130211  9:45:04 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
130211  9:45:04 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130211  9:45:04 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
130211  9:45:04 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130211  9:45:04 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
130211  9:45:04  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
```

Does anyone know why this is happen? I am really need advice, my boss is getting mad.. :D

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 7):

This is normal output after a crash.  InnoDB is designed to recover automatically in these cases, but it may take some time.  Usually minutes, but possibly hours if the crash occurred when you had thousands of pages of modified data in memory, and your disks are slow.

Despite what @tadman says, it's not necessarily going to trash your data.  InnoDB can recover by itself in most cases, with no data loss.

It is possible for InnoDB to be corrupted in a crash more severely, and it's possible that it won't be able to recover in all cases.   But the error log output you show doesn't show any report of unrecoverable damage.  The messages are normal output when starting up the MySQL Service after a crash.  Wait for it to complete until it says "ready for connections" and then connect and do some ad hoc queries to check if the data looks correct to you.

As for what caused the crash, there are many possible causes.  For instance, it would happen if you powered off the computer suddenly.  Or if you killed the MySQL Service.  You asked about viruses in another comment.  In theory, a virus could deliberately kill the MySQL Service.

Or possibly it's due to a software bug in MySQL.

That's right -- all software contains bugs!  Your boss can get mad about it, he can even demand to throw MySQL out and switch to some other database.  But there's no database software in the world that is 100% immune to bugs that cause crashes.

Comment: I tried to restart server several times and mysql server is working again. This is so wierd. Sometimesthe Apache won't start, sometimes mysql won't start. But in this case i just want mysql sever is working again. Yeah, there's no database software in the world that is 100% immune to bugs..i agree

Comment: Maybe related, [systemd not shutting down MariaDB properly?](https://serverfault.com/q/929030/145545)

Answer (score 1):

You trashed your server's InnoDB tables by hard crashing. Sometimes you will need to adjust a setting in `my.cnf` to enable [recovery mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html). Often the tables are in read-only mode so you will have to make back-ups, clear out your MySQL data directory, and re-initialize MySQL with `mysql-install-db` to start from scratch.

This should serve as a reminder to back up any and all important data.

Comment: It's possible if it caused by a virus? because we had a conficker virus issue for the last weeks... last time the apache service won't started, then I scanned it use antivirus and it detected many of conficker virus. It's possible if conficker cause mysql server down?

Comment: If your server ends up getting a virus, wipe, reinstall, and *patch* everything up to the current standards. Do not leave an infected server running and attached to your network. You do have back-ups, right?